# SEVERE: Servlet [-dispatcher] in web application [] threw load() exception

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, heroku

Hi I'm truing to build my first Maven Java Web Application with Spring and I use heroku to deploy my app. I can build app successfully but when I try to open link where my app is located I see error 404.
Here are my logs from heroku:

```
    2018-03-26T20:13:06.206990+00:00 app[web.1]: SEVERE: Servlet [-dispatcher] in web application [] threw load() exception
2018-03-26T20:13:06.206992+00:00 app[web.1]: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.DispatcherServlet
2018-03-26T20:13:06.206994+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285)
2018-03-26T20:13:06.206995+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
2018-03-26T20:13:06.206997+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:520)
2018-03-26T20:13:06.206999+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:501)
2018-03-26T20:13:06.207001+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
2018-03-26T20:13:06.207003+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1050)
2018-03-26T20:13:06.207004+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:989)
2018-03-26T20:13:06.207006+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4913)
2018-03-26T20:13:06.207008+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5223)
2018-03-26T20:13:06.207009+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
2018-03-26T20:13:06.207011+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
2018-03-26T20:13:06.207028+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
2018-03-26T20:13:06.207030+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2018-03-26T20:13:06.207032+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
2018-03-26T20:13:06.207033+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
2018-03-26T20:13:06.207037+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-03-26T20:13:06.207041+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-03-26T20:13:06.239514+00:00 app[web.1]: Mar 26, 2018 8:13:06 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
2018-03-26T20:13:06.239518+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler [http-nio-36917]
2018-03-26T20:13:06.808753+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=smok-prot-4.herokuapp.com request_id=8483e02d-3aa0-44e1-8abc-810f9f9c14ad fwd="46.22.168.229" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=895ms status=404 bytes=1141 protocol=https
2018-03-26T20:13:09.966331+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/Application/Test" host=smok-prot-4.herokuapp.com request_id=243f54a3-9a3a-4004-8315-1ccbaa965208 fwd="46.22.168.229" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=14ms status=404 bytes=1141 protocol=https
Disconnected from log stream. There may be events happening that you do not see here! Attempting to reconnect...
2018-03-26T20:13:06.207028+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
2018-03-26T20:13:06.207030+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2018-03-26T20:13:06.207032+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
2018-03-26T20:13:06.207033+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
2018-03-26T20:13:06.207037+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-03-26T20:13:06.207041+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-03-26T20:13:06.239518+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler [http-nio-36917]
2018-03-26T20:13:06.239514+00:00 app[web.1]: Mar 26, 2018 8:13:06 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
2018-03-26T20:13:06.808753+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=smok-prot-4.herokuapp.com request_id=8483e02d-3aa0-44e1-8abc-810f9f9c14ad fwd="46.22.168.229" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=895ms status=404 bytes=1141 protocol=https
2018-03-26T20:13:09.966331+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/Application/Test" host=smok-prot-4.herokuapp.com request_id=243f54a3-9a3a-4004-8315-1ccbaa965208 fwd="46.22.168.229" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=14ms status=404 bytes=1141 protocol=https
```

Here is structure of my project:

[structure of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dr0Cp.png)

And my files:

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>SMOKTestServer</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>SMOKTestServer Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
     <groupId>junit</groupId>
     <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
     <version>4.11</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
     <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
     <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
     <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>SMOKTestServer</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals><goal>copy</goal></goals>
                <configuration>
                    <artifactItems>
                        <artifactItem>
                            <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
                            <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                            <version>8.5.11.2</version>
                            <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                        </artifactItem>
                    </artifactItems>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app
  version="3.0"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

 <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
   org.springframework.web.context.DispatcherServlet
  </servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

 <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/view-resolver-servlet.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>

 <listener>
  <listener-class>
   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
  </listener-class>
 </listener>
</web-app>
```

And ApplicationController.java

```
package com.test.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class ApplicationController {

   @RequestMapping(value="/Test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String welcome(ModelMap model) {
      model.addAttribute("msgArgument", "Maven Java Web Application Project: Success!");

      return "index";
   }

   @RequestMapping(value="/Print/{arg}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String welcomeName(@PathVariable String arg, ModelMap model) {
      model.addAttribute("msgArgument", "Maven Java Web Application Project, input variable: " + arg);

      return "index";
   }
}
```

Please help me find the solution of my problem. What have I change to make my app works?

UPDATE: here are two links from my app that should works:

https://smok-prot-4.herokuapp.com/Application/Test

https://smok-prot-4.herokuapp.com

UPDATE 2: File view-resolver-servlet.xml looks lika that:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.controller" />

 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix">
   <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
  </property>
  <property name="suffix">
   <value>.jsp</value>
  </property>
 </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: How are you trying to access your app? Please, update the question with this link.

Comment: @SergeiSirik updated

Comment: Have you tried to access it this way https://smok-prot-4.herokuapp.com/webapp-runner/Application/Test ?

Comment: @SergeiSirik I have just tried your link, it does not work as well as mine :(

Comment: Also, actually, I don't see "/Application/" part of the url configured anywhere. Why do you think it has to be accessible on this path? From you config it is either ../Test or .../webapp-runner/Test.

Comment: @SergeiSirik yeach, probably it must be easier, I'm beginner at Java Web Applications, but I tried all endings that you suggest and all of them return same page with error 404

Comment: Hmmm, could you provide this file then from your app `<param-value>/WEB-INF/view-resolver-servlet.xml</param-value>` ?

Comment: @SergeiSirik I added view-resolver-servlet.xml